# Create new Minecraft server using existing map/world and RandomSeed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is it possible to turn a Minecraft single player map into multi-player server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server)

#### Problem

- I want to create a new Minecraft Server using [Bukkit](http://forums.bukkit.org/pages/about-us/).
- I have an old world that I want to be part of the new world. So I edited the old one with [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/), i.e. surrounding it with Bedrock and creating new chunks far from that old world and moving the spawn point there.

#### Questions

- *Copy existing "world" to new Server:* Is it correct to copy a "world"-folder and only deleting the "players"-folder in it? Or do I have to adapt more than that to have a properly functioning world afterwards?
- *Random Seed*: In the resulting world, I do not want to have any limitations of world generation because I flicked something together there. In MCEdit I can change the RandomSeed number. Is it of any importance that this number is the same like the one in the "server.properties"-file of the new Server will be? (In MCEdit I create the "start" of the new world, far away of the old. This will only be one to a few chunks.) When leaving RandomSeed in server.properties blank, it will use different Seeds every time, right? Than it would be no problem I guess.
- *World generation:* Because I take the old world, generated with an older Minecraft version, as a starting point, will this limit the world generation in newer Mincraft versions? Does the world folder somehow contain generation parameters apart from the RandomSeed so even with a newer Minecraft version the world is still generated like it would be in the old version?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30130/how-does-minecraft-1-8-handle-saves-generated-in-previous-versions

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20692/is-it-possible-to-turn-a-minecraft-single-player-map-into-multi-player-server) for information on how to copy a world from singleplayer to a server

If the world was generated in an older version of Minecraft, due to changes in the terrain generation, new chunks will not line up correctly, as shown in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30130/how-does-minecraft-1-8-handle-saves-generated-in-previous-versions)