# How to blend (fix) broken biome transitions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there an easy way to fix [broken biome transitions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30131/6377) that happen due to game updates? Any good editors that are used to smooth this transitions up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way is manually I'm afraid, or generate a new world. My usual tactic when there's a terrain generator update is:

1. Get [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/)
2. Open my old world, and copy the section I want to keep (usually just my main base, not too big)
3. Open Minecraft and generate a new world using the updated terrain generator
4. Find a big area of ocean in the new world (not too hard to find usually)
5. Using MCEdit again, plonk my section of old world into the ocean, or affixed to the edge of a land mass (you can also put it into a biome of the same type, but ocean is easier)
6. Spend a happy afternoon 'tidying up' the edges and making the terrain look believable again.

Comment: All the more reason to build my base on an island!

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before back when they first altered the biome generation alogrithm. It worked great back then. I haven't needed to use it again, so I can't confirm it still works with the new versions. https://github.com/gmcnew/bestofboth